# gnome-shell keyboard shortcuts (or extensions) for switching workspaces by most recently used (MRU) order?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

Having recently switched to gnome, I see there's no shortcut for switch to the previously used workspace - only absolute, next/prev (+/- 1), and first/last:

```
❯ gsettings list-recursively | grep 'org\.gnome.*switch.*workspace'
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 ['<Super>7']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 ['<Super>8']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 ['<Super>9']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 ['<Super>1']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 ['<Super>2']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-last ['<Super>End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 ['<Super>3']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left ['<Primary><Super>p']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right ['<Primary><Super>n']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-10 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 ['<Super>4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-11 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 ['<Super>5']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 ['<Super>6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-12 @as []
org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only false
org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-switch-workspace true
org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

This is with version 3.38.5. Is there any way to do this in a newer version or with an extension?